# How to store only the numeric values stored in the txt file on cmd?

Tags: cmd

How to store only the numeric values stored in the txt file on cmd?

****My txt file****

```
Name     #text 
----     ----- 
BootTime 207018
```

There is a space at the top. (The total number of lines is 4.)

---

**I tried this method:**

```
for  /f  "tokens=4  delims=  "  %a  IN  ('command')  do  set  result=%a
```

---

My goal is to store the value of `207018` separately using the cmd command.

Comment: `for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %a IN  (t.txt) do echo set result=%a`. You need the second token, not the fourth and avoid doubling spaces. The double space after `delims=` is the reason your loop doesn't work (don't ask me why though...).

Comment: You could skip the first three lines with `skip=3`, but it isn't really necessary, as in the end, the variable will contain the second token of the last (non-empty) line. Also `delims= ` isn't strictly necessary because SPACEs are standard delimiters anyway.